# como puedo hacer un loop o repetir todo un proceso

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: en el siguiente ejemplo lo que se intenta es: cuando se pregunta la edad y se ha verificado a través del WHILE y del INT que se ha colocado una letra se debe repetir todo el proceso hasta que el usuario ingrese un numero de. como puedo lograr esto? Gracias.]

en el siguiente ejemplo lo que se intenta es: cuando se pregunta la edad y se ha verificado a través del WHILE y del INT que se ha colocado una letra se debe repetir todo el proceso hasta que el usuario ingrese un numero de. como puedo lograr esto? Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basicamente cambiando el condicional y dejando todo en el bucle:

```
#-*- coding: utf  -8 -*-
print("¿Cuántos años tienes? ")
edad=input(">> ")
while True:
    if len(edad) == 0 :
        print("Disculpa, ¿cuántos años tienes?")
        edad = input(">>")
    
    try :
        convertnum = int(edad)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("No te entiendo, ¿cuántos años tienes?")
        edad=input(">> ")
```

El bucle se repetirá hasta llegar al break
Si es mayor a 0 se ejecuta el try

Comment: Repites innecesariamente varias cosas

Comment: Otra cosa es que debías indicarle al OP que su código tiene que ir como texto

Comment: @Christian  simplemente muestro como funcionaría su código. no es mi intención cambiarle toda su lógica de programación, para eso están ustedes y lo de "indicarle" sobre  el texto también lo hacen otros.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría así

```
while True:
    try:
        edad = int(input("¿Cuál es tu edad?"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Intenta de nuevo, ¿Cuál es tu edad?")
    else:
        break
```

la declaración `else` del `try` se ejecuta si no sucede la excepción de tal forma que cuando el valor dado por el usuario corresponda a un número se romperá el `while`, "mientras" no sea así no terminará el buble.

Comment: Algo curioso es que si pongo `16_6` también funciona y el resultado es `166` :D.

Comment: Otra cosa es que debías indicarle al OP que su código tiene que ir como texto

Comment: @Christian ya se lo dijo Gbianchi, por que repetirlo?

Comment: @Christian la **indicación** ya se la hicieron o ¿acaso lo mejor es quedarse en la **indicación** y no colaborar con la respuesta? si esa es su actitud no es la mía.

Comment: No para nada, solo es bueno indicar que el código debe ir como texto (esto como recomendacion), además si solo dijeras la recomendación (sin dar solución al problema) no seria una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Quiza te sirva

```
while True:
    edad = input("Edad: ")
    try:
        convert_edad = int(edad)
        if convert_edad < 0:
            print("La edad no puede ser negativa")
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Asegurate que el valor ingresado sea un numero.")
print("Pasaste con exito. Tienes",edad,"años")
```

Se crea el bucle infinito a través del while True, en la cuarta linea se intenta transformar la entrada del usuario a entero. Sino se consigue la transformación, vuelve a pedir la edad.
La parte de:

```
    if convert_edad < 0:
        print("La edad no puede ser negativa")
    else:
        break
```

Se asegura que la entrada ya transformada no sea negativa, si es que es negativa vuelve a pedir la edad.

Comment: Por favor explica un  poco lo que haces. Las explicaciones siempre de agradecen